# PrimeFaces 5 Calendar: incoherent behaviour with and without TimePicker

Tags: date, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I have **two calendars:** `<p:calendar required="true" mask="true">` with a default date (current date). One has **date/time pattern** and the other has **date pattern only**.

**While testing invalid cases**, when inputting invalid dates (such as '33/33/3333' or '33/33/3333 33:33') or when leaving the field blank or incomplete, **PrimeFaces shows different behaviour depending on the pattern:**

- In the **date only calendar**, PrimeFaces nicely shows the expected error message in a growl, and leaves the field as it was typed.
- In the **date/time calendar**, PrimeFaces reverts the field to the last valid entered date, and shows no growl.

**Is there a way to make both calendars behave the same way?** If possible, I'd like to show the growl AND revert the field to the last valid value.

Code:

```
<p:calendar
   id="calDtInicial"
   value="#{cadastrar_contrato.dtInicial}"
   maxlength="10" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
   mask="true" required="true" locale="pt"
>
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />
    <f:validator validatorId="sgrp.DateValidator" />
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" global="false"
            update="calDtInicial calDtFinal" />
    <p:ajax event="change" global="false"
            update="calDtInicial calDtFinal :theForm:growl" />
</p:calendar>
```

-

```
<p:calendar
   id="calDtFinal"
   value="#{cadastrar_contrato.dtFinal}"
   maxlength="10" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
   mask="true" required="true" locale="pt"
>
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    <f:validator validatorId="sgrp.DateValidator" />
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" global="false"
            update="calDtInicial calDtFinal" />
    <p:ajax event="change" global="false"
            update="calDtInicial calDtFinal :theForm:growl" />
</p:calendar>
```

PrimeFaces 5, JSF 2.1.

Comment: I also noticed that the action/actionListener events in the back bean are fired regardless of the validation error when time is used in the mask.